# Event observer for multi select attribute in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, event-observer

I want to get new added option or all option at the time of save multiselect attribute from admin.

**Which event I need to use for multiselect attribute save?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the event which we use for attribute save

> catalog_entity_attribute_save_after

Here we can get current attribute option by `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository`

```
if ($attrCode == "MyAttribute")
{
    $attributeOptions = $this->repository->get($attrCode)->getOptions();
    ....
    ....
}
```